# How to be able to use [Customers] instead of [DatabaseName].[dbo].[Customers] in SQL server queries

Tags: sql, t-sql

This should be a relatively simple thing to do. Basically I have SQL Server 2008, and I have attached `NorthWind` database to it. This is my query which works fine.

```
SELECT [Customers].[CompanyName], [Orders].[OrderID]
FROM [Northwind].[dbo].[Customers]
LEFT JOIN [Northwind].[dbo].[Orders]
ON Orders.CustomerID=Customers.CustomerID
ORDER BY Customers.CompanyName;
```

In the second SQL line, how can I go about being able to do

```
FROM [Customers]
```

Instead of

```
FROM [Northwind].[dbo].[Customers]
```

Is it possible? or is it not the right way to do it?  I have 3 more databases attached to SQL Server by the way and `NorthWind`is not the only one. I googled it but I am not quite sure what terms to google. I just want to shorten my queries. Thank you

Comment: Please note that it is a good practice to always use schema.tableName instead of just tableName. So even if FROM [Customers] will work when you write 'USE Northwind', you should still always use [dbo].[Customers] instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways that you can do this.

When you open a new query window in SSMS you can add the following line to the top:

```
    USE Northwind
```

Or when you open a new query window you can change the database in the dropdown menu on the SQL Editor toolbar to Northwind, see screenshot:

[image]

Finally, when working in the Northwind data base, if you open a new query window, it should default to that database.

Comment: Thanks.Accepted and +1 for your effort for doing [PrintScreen] for the picture illustration. :D

Answer (score 6):

At the beginning of your query indicate what database you are using.

```
USE [Northwind]
```

Answer (score 1):

Add
`Use [Northwind]` before the query

OR

Select the `Northwind` database from the database dropdown, if using SSMS

OR

Start a new query window by right-clicking on the `Northwind` database and selecting new query option

(All are the one and the same thing)